# String split words from numbers and maintain fixed substring count

Tags: r, string, pdf

I have a balance sheet in a pdf. It has 4 columns; the variable name, value in the current year, value in the prior year, and the difference between the current and prior year. I don't have permission to share the pdf but this is an example of what it looks like.

This is the code I tried using:

```
Assets <- BS[4:40] %>%
  trimws("l") %>%
  strsplit(split = "\\s{2,}"); Assets
```

But it doesn't count the extra space as a substring for instances of missing values.

The object is called Assets and it contains the following:

```
 [1] "                                                        Current                  Prior Year         Change"                                                                                                                                                                                                    
 [2] "  CASH                                              $99,999,999.00               $99,999,999.00     ($0.00)"  
 [3] "  CASH SLIPS                                        1,000,000.00                 1,000,000.00         0.00"   
 [4] "  BONDS                                                                       500,000.00           (500,000.00)" 
 [5] "  ACCOUNTS RECEIVABLE                              1,000,000.00               2,000,000.00       (1,000,000.00)"
```

1. I'd like to end up with a data frame with 4 columns; Line_Item, Current_Year, Prior_Year, Change.
2. I'd like to split each string from [2:5] into 4 substrings. The name of the line item and the 3 numerical values. Line 2 has a dollar sign so I need to remove that. Line 4 does not have a current value so I need to automatically include a zero in its place.

The desired dataframe output:

```
     Line_Item                                         Current_Year                     Prior_Year             Change
     CASH                                             99,999,999.00                  99,999,999.00               0.00  
     CASH SLIPS                                        1,000,000.00                   1,000,000.00               0.00   
     BONDS                                                     0.00                     500,000.00       (500,000.00) 
     ACCOUNTS RECEIVABLE                               1,000,000.00                   2,000,000.00     (1,000,000.00)
```

the dput:

```
list(c("CASH", "$99,999,999.00", "$99,999,999.00", "0.00"), 
    c("CASH SLIPS", "1,000,000.00", "1,000,000.00", "0.00"
    ), c("BONDS", "500,000.00", "(500,000.00)"
    ), c("ACCOUNTS RECEIVABLE", "1,000,000.00", "2,000,000.00", 
    "(1,000,000.00)"))
```

Comment: It's a list of characters.

Comment: In the 4th element, there is no 0 for the Current Year.  How do you decide the position of blank

Comment: I’m stuck on that. I was hoping it was possible to do it intuitively.

Comment: the issue is that blanks in Current_Year or Prior_Year cannot be determined unless there are some rules

Comment: could you include the results of  `dput(Assets)` in your question

Comment: How about using the sign of the Change column to indicate which year is missing. So if the count of substrings is three and the change is negative then the current year is missing. Would that work?

Comment: There could be case where 2 or 3 columns can be missing

Comment: There won’t be a case where 2 columns will be missing. It will always be 1 or no columns missing.

Comment: @Onyambu Unfortunately I can’t share the data. I manually created the example above.

Comment: could you post the dput of the example above then?

Comment: @Onyambu I've included the dput in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a function that determines whether the third value is missing:

```
m <- function(x){
  if(length(x)==4) return(x)
  if(grepl("\\)", x[3]))  c(x[1],0,x[-1])
  else c(x[1:2],0, x[3])
}
         
data.frame(t(sub("\\$","",sapply(mystring, m))))
                   X1            X2            X3             X4
1                CASH 99,999,999.00 99,999,999.00           0.00
2          CASH SLIPS  1,000,000.00  1,000,000.00           0.00
3               BONDS             0    500,000.00   (500,000.00)
4 ACCOUNTS RECEIVABLE  1,000,000.00  2,000,000.00 (1,000,000.00)
```